# Bootstrap - How to span a column using container/row/col classes

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create the equivalent using Bootstrap and I understand the use of container and the use of DIVs with class="row" and class="col". I just dont know how I would do a colspan like in HTML when you use TABLE s.

With example below "Sum: $180" how do I do that using a Container with DIV cols and rows

[image]

Comment: At first glance, that last `div` should have `col-12` class. Please provide a [mcve] so we can follow along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for you:

```
<div class="container border">
   <div class="row border">
      <div class="col border">Column</div>
      <div class="col border">Column</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row border">
      <div class="col-12">Column</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As ths says in the comments, the col-12 is the key.

I used the help document from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/ to build the code above. I added the borders for visibility.

Depending on your usage you might need to watch out for the responsiveness of the grid on smaller screens as the columns will wrap underneath each other.

Hope this helps.